# Sort 3d array by 1st level keys, then the 2nd level by lone 3rd level key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    'user 1' => [
        ['item 4' => '11385'],
        ['item 2' => '144268'],
        ['item 1' => '65774'],
        ['item 9' => '98523'],
    ],
    'user 5' => [
        ['item 8' => '239233'],
    ],
    'user 2' => [
        ['item 4' => '53718'],
        ['item 1' => '154687'],
    ],
]
```

What I need to do is to simply sort my array first by users (first level keys), then by items (third level keys) ascending.

Desired result:

```
[
    'user 1' => [
        ['item 1' => '65774'],
        ['item 2' => '144268'],
        ['item 4' => '11385'],
        ['item 9' => '98523'],
    ],
    'user 2' => [
        ['item 1' => '154687'],
        ['item 4' => '53718'],
    ],
    'user 5' => [
        ['item 8' => '239233'],
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ksort` sorts by the key

```
$newArray = array();

# start by sorting users
$yourArray = ksort($yourArray);

# then sort sub items
foreach($yourArray as $user=>$theirItems) {
    $theirItems = ksort($theirItems); # assuming you still want to sort by key;
    $newArray[$user] = $theirItems;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Output: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lCC7P))

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, true given
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/function.usort.php) then create two comparison functions and sort your array using them one after one.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by first level keys, then by the  key of the firat element in each subarray, call `ksort()` then sort within each set of data by the lone element's key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UoSMX))

```
ksort($array);
foreach ($array as &$v) {
    usort(
        $v,
        fn($a, $b) => key($a) <=> key($b)
    );
}
var_export($array);
```

Or with `array_myltisort()` for fewer total iterated function calls: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CbG1J))

```
ksort($array);
foreach ($array as &$v) {
    array_multisort(
        array_map('key', $v),
        $v
    );
}
var_export($array);
```